# Плавное приближение камеры при старте Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать заскриптованую камеру в Юнити? По такому сценарию:
1.Камера показывает всю сцену целиком 1 секунду.
2. Плавно подлетает к объекту.

В целом мне не ясна часть только с плавным подлетом к объекту, ибо все мои попытки трансформить камеру выполнялись моментально.

Comment: можно сделать примерно так: `camPosition = lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, time);` где `time` меняется от `0` до `1` в течение всего времени перелета

Comment: @StrangerintheQ С перемещением через лерп как раз не возникло проблем, но как динамически менять время?

Comment: запомнить время старта и вычитать это значение из текущего времени в каждом кадре

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил примерно таким образом:

```cs
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset;
        [SerializeField] private int delayTime = 1;
        private float time;
        private GameObject player;
        private bool zoomStatus;

        private void Start()
        {
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            StartCoroutine(ScriptedCamera());
        }

        void Update()
        {
            CameraZoomStatus(zoomStatus);
        }

        private void CameraZoomStatus(bool status)
        {
            if (!status) return;
            time += 0.001f * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, player.transform.position + offset, time);
        }


        private IEnumerator ScriptedCamera()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);

            zoomStatus = true;
        }
    }
```